# readyread is not emitted

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkreply

I am trying to do that fetching a web page on QT. I want to do this fetching operation over a class. However my readyread signal which is in startRequest function is not emitted. I couldn't take any data. This code creates HTML file, but doesn't write anything into it.

```
#include "fetchoperation.h"
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;
fetchoperation::fetchoperation()
{

}
void fetchoperation::downloadFile(QUrl geturl,QString th)
{
    page=th;
    qnam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    url=geturl;
    QFileInfo fileInfo(url.path());
    QString fileName = fileInfo.fileName();
    fileName = "C:/yunus/"+page+".html";
    file = new QFile(fileName);
    file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    startRequest(url);


}
void fetchoperation::httpReadyRead()
{
    if (file)
        file->write(reply->readAll());
}
void fetchoperation::httpDownloadFinished()
{   
    file->flush();
    file->close();

    QVariant redirectionTarget = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);
             QString fileName = QFileInfo(QUrl(url).path()).fileName();

         reply->deleteLater();
         reply = 0;
         delete file;
         file = 0;
        QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/yunus/"+page+".html"));
}
void fetchoperation::startRequest(QUrl url)
{   

    reply = qnam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));

    connect(reply,&QNetworkReply::readyRead,
            this,&fetchoperation::httpReadyRead);

    connect(reply,&QNetworkReply::finished,
            this,&fetchoperation::httpDownloadFinished);
}
```

Comment: When does `downloadFile` get called, as this is where the `file` object is created? If the file is NULL, `httpReadRead` won't write to the file in this case. I suggest improving your question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How did you _use_ this class in the body of your application, do you create an object ? where ?

Comment: I create object in another class, so I call this class from another class. Is it create a problem?